# 2010 Workflow Spamming

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-tasks-list

I'm at a standstill, this is a task list where I've created a workflow (I only have WF 2010 available) to notify people during different stages.  This is like the 6th iteration and I'm banging my head against a wall.  The people who are receiving the email (bcc, to) keep getting the same emails over and over. This is the last step and this whole product can go live. I will take any and all help!

[image: Current Workflow]

Comment: You need to identify which conditions is responsible for the spamming. You need to trace it from workflow history. Store the variables you think are causing the issue in history.

Comment: What is the settings of this workflow? Does workflow fire on item changing?

Comment: It does.  Which is necessary as there are at least 40 active IT requests at a time.  Which makes things cumbersome when the technicians update the status of the request